# QGIS 3.4, plugin builder, refresh layers

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3, refresh

I created a very simple plugin with the plugin builder for GIS 3.4. Wihtout any GUI-Widget - by clicking the plugin  button I just want to save the edits from several layers at one time and start the edit mode again. That works fine. But in the end I want to refresh the map (what I can do by clicking seperatly the refresh button, but I would like to have this function in my plugin). I tried it like this (but the last row is not working):

```
def run(self):
    """Run method that performs all the real work"""
    layer_edit = [ 'neuer Baumpunkt', 'baeume_akt','kontrolle','schaeden_akt','massnahmen_akt']
    price = 6.0
    for layers in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
        if layers.name() in layer_edit:
            layers.commitChanges()
            layers.startEditing()
            layers.refresh()
```

But there is an AttributeError:`'QgsVectorLayer' object has no attribute 'refresh'` The same is with `refreshAllLayers()`. 
I'm only started working with python, so I'm a very beginner.

I tried what  Germán Carrillo suggested like this:

```
def run(self):
    """Run method that performs all the real work"""
    layer_edit = [ 'neuer Baumpunkt', 'baeume_akt','kontrolle','schaeden_akt','massnahmen_akt']
    price = 6.0
    for layers in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
        if layers.name() in layer_edit:
            layers.commitChanges()
            layers.startEditing()
    self.iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

But it doesn't work.

The beginning of my skript looks like this:

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QSettings, QTranslator, QCoreApplication
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import QIcon
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QAction
from qgis.core import QgsProject
# Initialize Qt resources from file resources.py
from .resources import *
# Import the code for the dialog
from .bk_save_dialog import BK_speichernDialog
import os.path

class BK_speichern:
"""QGIS Plugin Implementation."""

   def __init__(self, iface):
       """Constructor.

       :param iface: An interface instance that will be passed to this class
           which provides the hook by which you can manipulate the QGIS
           application at run time.
       :type iface: QgsInterface
       """
       # Save reference to the QGIS interface
       self.iface = iface
       # initialize plugin directory
       self.plugin_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
       # initialize locale
       locale = QSettings().value('locale/userLocale')[0:2]
       locale_path = os.path.join(
           self.plugin_dir,
           'i18n',
           'BK_speichern_{}.qm'.format(locale))

       if os.path.exists(locale_path):
           self.translator = QTranslator()
           self.translator.load(locale_path)
           QCoreApplication.installTranslator(self.translator)

       # Declare instance attributes
       self.actions = []
       self.menu = self.tr(u'&Baumkontrolle speichern')

       # Check if plugin was started the first time in current QGIS session
       # Must be set in initGui() to survive plugin reloads
       self.first_start = None
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To refresh all layers, you can use the following command : `iface.mapCanvas().refreshAllLayers()`

In your case : 
`self.iface.mapCanvas().refreshAllLayers()`

The following script work (I write out of a function) :

```
from qgis.utils import iface

layer_edit = [ 'Enveloppe concave', 'Sortie SQL','Channel']
for layers in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
    if layers.name() in layer_edit:
        layers.commitChanges()
        layers.startEditing()

    iface.mapCanvas().refreshAllLayers()`
```

Comment: I got the error `NameError: name 'iface' is not defined`. How/where can I define it? I will add the beginning of the skript in my question. I just startet with python...

Comment: add this line at the beginning : `from qgis.utils import iface`

Comment: it works like this! Thank you very much!